# hide ID mod_rewrite

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

is there a way to hide IDs using only .htaccess and without changing my php code?

htt://www.domain.com/show.php?categoryID=2&cname=electronic&productid=21&name=laptops

to

htt://www.domain.com/electronics/laptops

thanks in advance.

Comment: How do cname, name and productid correspond? How would the system know what product to look up if it doesn't get an ID?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "not changing php code"? You would of course have to edit links, too.

Comment: I just wanted not to change my query which is basing on the ID.

Answer (score 2):

In your .htaccess you can put:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(electronics|other|categories|here)/(laptops|other|products|here)/$ shop.php?cname=$1&name=$2
```

Basically I made a RegEx that matches all of your products and all of your categories, and broke that out into the cname and name and passed them to show.php.

However note I didn't pass the ID numbers to your show script.  Rewrite Engine can't figure those out for you, your script will need to take the names and look up the ids itself.